# Using pgfgantt: compilation issue

Tags: pgfgantt

I'm fairly new to latex and while using pgfgantt package to create a gantt chart, I ran into a compilation issue I can't seem to figure out.

There's no error message or anything, but the code won't stop building for a long time that I eventually have to stop the process. I'm using texmaker on Mac environment. I think there might be an issue with where I unzipped the .sty files? I had to create texmf folder in my ~/Library directory, and all the packages are within ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/gantclass. I have a folder that I don't remember creating called texlive. Was I supposed to put the files in there instead?

My code is as follows:

```
\subsection*{Timeline}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{14}
        \gantttitle{Two-Week Project Timeline} \\
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,14}{1} \\
        \ganttbar{Gather Tweets}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Curate Comments}{3}{7} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}
        \ganttbar{Implement Naive Bayes}{6}{11} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Train}{9}{11} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{11} \\
        \ganttbar{Evaluate}{11}{13} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{13} \\
        \ganttbar{Test}{14} \\
    \end{ganttchart}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX Stack Exchange! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the error. You forgot an argument for `\gantttitle` and one for `\ganttbar`. Take a look at this code (the comments indicate the fixes):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Timeline}
    \begin{ganttchart}{1}{15}
        \gantttitle{Two-Week Project Timeline}{15} \\ %missing number of time slots
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,14}{1} \\
        \ganttbar{Gather Tweets}{1}{2} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Curate Comments}{3}{7} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}
        \ganttbar{Implement Naive Bayes}{6}{11} \\
        \ganttlinkedbar{Train}{9}{11} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{11} \\
        \ganttbar{Evaluate}{11}{13} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{13} \\
        \ganttbar{Test}{14}{15} \\%missing end slot
    \end{ganttchart}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, that was it! thank you! For some reason, I thought that if it was a syntax issue, the compiler would tell me instead of running forever... : ) thanks for the answer!